# replace with regular expression in azure devops

Tags: powershell, azure, yaml, azure-devops, azure-devops-server

I want to take this buildVariable

```
Build.SourceVersion
```

which will equal for example:

> 0gc58d92d905d62415b8866g3f48f17416da426s

And replace from digit [7] till line end with empty string

> 0gc58d92

I tried

`- ShortCommitId: ${{ replace(variables['Build.SourceVersion'], '[[8]-$]','') }}`

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The [substring()](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html) method will take the string value from `Build.SourceVersion` and can be passed two `int` parameters. One will output the string value starting at a specific character position, and the other tell it what subsequent character positions characters to output.

```
$a = "0gc58d92d905d62415b8866g3f48f17416da426s"
$a.substring(0,7)
```

**Output**

```
0gc58d9
```

Pass the [substring()](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html) method just one `int` parameter telling it the starting character position to just output all subsequent character position characters until the end of the string.

```
$a = "0gc58d92d905d62415b8866g3f48f17416da426s"
$a.substring(8)
```

**Output**

```
d905d62415b8866g3f48f17416da426s
```

### Supporting Resource

- [Substring()](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html)
- [String.Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0)

  > `Substring(Int32)`
  >
  > - Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.
  >
  > `Substring(Int32, Int32)`
  >
  > - Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

Comment: This solution should help you get what you need, but let me know if you run into any snag, I'm happy to adjust to accommodate further if needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't

Comment: @Shnbook If you have this value to start with `0gc58d92d905d62415b8866g3f48f17416da426s` what is the desired (or an example) final result you want that to be. I probably just need to understand better but if you can help clarify a little further to help me better understand, I should be able to help you figure out what you need. Let me know.

Comment: @Shnbook See above comment but if you can share more of the fully logic in a script, etc. you are using, that may help me fine tune this method better for your use case. Otherwise, I'm left to play with a string basically but if that's not working for your command when you integrate it, I just need to see more logic to see what trivial adjustments are needed to make it work properly.